# iOS6, android and position:fixed and scaling

Tags: android, ios, css

I have a website with the following configuration:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=5.0;minimum-scale=1.0;user-scalable=1;" />
```

and a div element with the

```
<div style="position:fixed;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:40px;">Fixed Header Content</div>
```

(you can find the example here: http://massmatics.de/demo/test.html)

When watching this site on iOS and zooming, the size of this element increases but is getting out of the zoomed area.

When performing the same action on android (tested on a Nexus Tablet with Android 4.x) the fixed element disapears while zooming but when this action is finished it appears in a increased version on the zoomed area.

I think the behavior of chrome is right, but my question is now:

Is there a way to get the same behavior on android as on iOS?

The reason why I am asking is that I have a lot of content on the page which should be zoomed when viewed on a small device, but on Android the enlarged fixed element is taking all the space so zooming is not really a advantage.

Best regards

Update: I added a JS Implementation of the position:fixed to my example (with bad performance, I know, just for testing purposes.) - still the same behavior as with position:fixed. Is there an event whether the user zooms the page?

Comment: Using `fixed` on mobile versions isn't really possible as it doesn't really work with the way that mobile devices render pages - as you scroll. They can be nice on desktops but for mobile I'd just have it at the top of the page.

Comment: I do not have a problem with the implementation of `fixed`, this works nicely on iOS6 and chrome on android 4.x The only problem is the different implementation when zooming the page.

Answer (score 0):

position:fixed support was just added last year in iOS5 - and from my experience, Android handles such elements inconsistently.

I believe the only predictable way to accomplish what you are trying to do is to wire it all up with JavaScript. Probably not the answer you were hoping for, but position:fixed is rarely the right solution on mobile anyway.

Comment: do you have a special js implementation in mind? I updated my example from above with a jQuery version, but the behavior when zooming on android is the same as with `position:fixed`.